# It's possible to find the probability distribution for X-Y, known only mean and variance?

Tags: probability-distributions, random-variables

> X, Y are random variables such that $E[X] = 1, Var[X] = 2, E[X] = 3
> > Var[Y] = 2, E[XY] = 5$.  It's possible to find the probability
> distribution for X-Y?

It is easy to check that X and Y aren't independent.

Comment: No. Unless they are part of some parametric family, which you haven’t specified. The intuition should be that **general** distributions have many, many degrees of freedom. However, you have only specified a handful of constraints.

Comment: You may want to fix the typos in your question.